# As a library: How to provide default JCache implementation

Tags: java, maven, jcache

Assume I write a library and want to cache the result some long running or fragile tasks. For that I use the `JCache` API in my code.

So my `pom.xml` will contain a dependency entry like

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- does this even make sense? -->
</dependency>
```

Based on this I would now want to know how I can make the usage for the user as easy as possible?

The two options I see are both sub-optimal and I have the feeling that this must be some kind of common "problem", so there is probably a common solution I am not aware of.

1. I provide an implementation of the JCache API myself.

   +: The user/consumer of my library can easily use it out of the box without the need to provide anything.

   -: If a custom, user specific implementation should be used it's necessary to exclude this implementation from my library on a maven level.

   -: Potential clashes between multiple libraries doing this.
2. I don't provide any implementation the JCache API.

   +: No clashes with other libraries or any custom implementation the consumer of my library wants to use.

   -: It is necessary to provide a JCache implementation, even if the consumer is not aware that there is caching involved.

This looks very much like the logging setup, where I use `slf4j-api` in my application and the consumer needs to provide an implementation themselves. But logging feels a bit more common then caching to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you laid out the pros and cons of the different approaches pretty well already. So I pick your two approaches and give some additional hints:

> 1. I provide an implementation of the JCache API myself.

1.1:
You can use the maven shade plugin to move the JCache API and the implementation to a different package. Then you have no conflicts. The downside of it, is confusion when the (original) source code is used for debugging.

1.2:
You can keep the original JCache API and use a shaded version of an implementation. There might be conflicts with applications expecting one or "their" default implementation. You can circumvent this by not using the normal SPI mechanism for instantiation.

> 2. I don't provide any implementation the JCache API.

The caching implementations differ a lot in terms of features and configuration. I would recommend that you have at least one setup with an implementation and configuration that works OOTB. Either with a dependency to an implementation or via a bundled shaded implementation.

If you use a maven dependency, users may exclude the caching implementation and use their own if they have a different preference or requirements.

I would recommend to just keep things simple and start with a dependency and then see what users may want or where the problems arise. Better then making things complicated right from the start.